# Count frequency of value in pandas column where values in another column are similar

Tags: python, pandas, count, frequency

Given a `pandas` `dataframe` that looks as below `column_a` and `column_b`. How can I construct 2 additional columns, one that counts the frequency of each value from `column_a` for all columns, and another that counts the unique number of values from where values in `column_a` are the same:

```
column_a | column_b | col_a_count | count_unique_b_where_a
  0           1           4         3
  0           1           4         3
  0           2           4         3
  0           3           4         3
  2           0           3         1
  2           0           3         1
  2           0           3         1 
  5           3           1         1
  9           5           6         5 
  9           5           6         5
  9           3           6         5
  9           4           6         5
  9           2           6         5
  9           1           6         5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `groupby` and `agg`:

```
s = (df.groupby('column_a').agg(
        {'column_a': 'count', 'column_b': 'nunique'}).reindex(df.column_a))
```

```
          column_a  column_b   
column_a                       
0                4         3   
0                4         3   
0                4         3   
0                4         3   
2                3         1   
2                3         1   
2                3         1   
5                1         1   
9                6         5   
9                6         5   
9                6         5   
9                6         5   
9                6         5   
9                6         5
```